# Merge fields expression in HTML content that can be pasted on a word document

Tags: merge, ms-word, field

I'm not sure how can I create merge fields (`<<field.name>>`) and place them inside HTML content that I can later copy to my clipboard and paste them it inside a Word or a LibreOffice file.

Comment: AFAIK, HTML alone can't encode something that Word will interpret as a field code. To do that, you have to use Word's non-standard "round-trip" HTML format. You may find the info in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59689248/word-html-format-insert-a-custom-toc-via-field-code useful, particularly the Answer by user12750785 , (but taking note of the comments). But if you copy the HTML *as text* into the Windows clipboard, Word will just paste that text rather than interpreting the HTML, so you may need to find a way to solve that problem too.